# Allocation of memory in x86-64

Tags: c, gcc, memory, 64-bit

I just want to make it clear to myself about memory allocation (if that's how I may call it correctly) in c on x64 architecture.

I have one program that simply outputs the location of the variable in the memory. I run it several times and then I see some strange thing going on:

The line of code:

```
printf("[*] test_val @ 0x%016llx = %d 0x%016llx\n", &test_val, test_val, test_val);
```

1st time:

```
[*] test_val @ 0x00005612f1edb050 = -72 0x00000000ffffffb8
```

2nd time:

```
[*] test_val @ 0x000055ec3b64f050 = -72 0x00000000ffffffb8
```

3rd time:

```
[*] test_val @ 0x00005577e99d4050 = -72 0x00000000ffffffb8
```

It seems that the memory location of the variable `test_int` is different every time except for the first 2.5 bits (00005) and the last 1.5 bits (the 050 part doesn't change).

There would've been no question, but in the book I'm learning by this address is constant all the time. The main difference is that this book is about 32bit architecture.

Do I understand correctly that the memory is being allocated dynamicly in x64 systems? Is there any way to "predict" where will the variable be, considering the fact that we know last 1.5 bits, 050 in this case?

Comment: Read about [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

Comment: @GovindParmar oh, thank you! It's just what I've been loking for

Comment: My guess would be that when your book says the address is constant "all the time" that it means *during one run of the program*.  If it says anything more general than that, then it is making assumptions that the language standard does not support, and that in fact are not universally true.  This has nothing in particular to do with 32-bit *vs*. 64-bit, nor with dynamic allocation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yeah, I understand. But in fact I didn't know what is ASLR untill the comment above told me about it. Now if I disable it, I may see that address is constant all the time, while I continiously running the program over and over again. Strange how it's not mentioned in the book, but still it solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There would've been no question, but in the book I'm learning by this address is constant all the time.

If this book actually *claimed* that addresses are to remain constant throughout multiple runs of the same program, it was wrong.  In fact, even during the same run of one program, local variables with automatic storage duration might get different addresses throughout multiple calls in the *same* running instance. Consider:

```
void foo()
{
    volatile int a = 12345;
    printf("%p\n", (void *)&a);
}
void bar()
{
    printf("In bar\n");
    foo();
}
int main()
{
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the output:

```
00B6FE58
In bar
00B6FE54
```

This is because the call to `bar` creates another frame on the stack when `foo` is entered, giving `a` a different address.  In general, the only thing that is safe to reason about, I believe, is if a variable has static storage duration, its address **should** remain constant throughout a *single run* of a program.

As for why you're observing different addresses when running your program multiple times, that's because:

1. The C Standard is agnostic to ABIs, executable file formats, and loaders.
2. [Advances in security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) generally mean you shouldn't expect to see the same addresses throughout multiple runs of a user-mode program on a modern operating system.

Comment: The age of the book could be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the operating system. However, it has become common for operating systems to load applications at random locations in memory. Compilers and linkers have produced relocatable code for decades but historically this was done to allow shared libraries to be loaded in different locations from different programs.

Now operating systems are loading the program at different locations. This is done as a security measure. The objective is to prevent crackers from manipulating specific memory locations.

The reason the last few bits of the address is the same is because the program is aligned on page boundaries.